# How find the closed form by this two sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

let $\{a_{n}\},\{b_{n}\}$ such $a_{1}=10,b_{1}=4$,and such
$$a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_{n}}{4}+\dfrac{3a_{n}+12}{4b^2_{n}}\\
b_{n+1}=\dfrac{b_{n}}{4}+\dfrac{a_{n}+7}{4b_{n}}$$
find the closed form $a_{n},b_{n}$

My try: since
$$a_{n+1}-\frac{a_{n}}{4}=3\dfrac{a_{n}+4}{4b^2_{n}}\tag{1}$$
$$b_{n+1}-\dfrac{b_{n}}{4}=\dfrac{a_{n}+7}{4b_{n}}\tag{2}$$
since $\dfrac{(1)}{(2)}$
$$\dfrac{4a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{4b_{n+1}-b_{n}}=\dfrac{3}{b_{n}}\cdot\dfrac{a_{n}+4}{a_{n}+7}$$

Comment: Are you _really_ looking for a closed form of $a_n$, $b_n$ or are you interested only in, for example, their behaviour in the limit?

Comment: Which is the source of the problem? This would maybe help some readers to try at least some rows of algebra, else there is a great chance that no such (relatively simple) explicit formula exists. And if we have the explicit formula, why is it important? (There are many cases of proposed problems, where somebody explicitly hides a trick, finding it is a non-structural task, takes its time, and at the end only a trick was maybe found...)

Comment: The sequences quickly reach one of the fixed points $a,b = (-6, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ and $(2,\pm \sqrt{3})$

Comment: @Christian: How did you do that so quickly?

Comment: You still haven't provided a source or any kind of background , I hope this is not from an ongoing(even now) competition. I also have doubts around the validity of the given definitions (it feels way too arbitrary), it would be nice if you could post the source of this question.

Comment: The sequence is quadratically converging to $(2,\sqrt3)$. So the definition is far from arbitrary. The numerators and denominators of $a_n,b_n$ grow as fast as those in Newton's method for $\sqrt3$ or $\sqrt2$. This did not help me yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: $\newcommand{\Z}{{\mathbb Z}}$A closed form solution is given by
$$a_n=\frac{r_n^2-q_n^2-p_n^2}{q_n^2},\ \ b_n=\frac{r_n}{q_n},$$
where $\displaystyle p_n=5^{2^{n-2}}$ and
$$\begin{array}lr_n=\tfrac1{4}\left((2\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^{2^{n-1}}(\sqrt2+1)^{2^{n-1}}+
    (-2\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^{2^{n-1}}(-\sqrt2+1)^{2^{n-1}} +\right.\\
\hspace{2cm}\left.(2\sqrt2-\sqrt3)^{2^{n-1}}(\sqrt2+1)^{2^{n-1}}+
    (-2\sqrt2-\sqrt3)^{2^{n-1}}(-\sqrt2+1)^{2^{n-1}}
\right)\\
q_n=\tfrac1{4\sqrt3}\left((2\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^{2^{n-1}}(\sqrt2+1)^{2^{n-1}}+
    (-2\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^{2^{n-1}}(-\sqrt2+1)^{2^{n-1}} -\right.\\
\hspace{2cm}\left.(2\sqrt2-\sqrt3)^{2^{n-1}}(\sqrt2+1)^{2^{n-1}}-
    (-2\sqrt2-\sqrt3)^{2^{n-1}}(-\sqrt2+1)^{2^{n-1}}
\right).
\end{array}$$
Remark: Using the reduction of the proof, it is possible to find closed form solutions in terms of almost all initial conditions.
The formulas are not as neet as in this special example. Using these
closed form solutions, it seems possible to describe the Julia set of the recursion in a simple way and to show that it does  not have a fractal nature. This, however, is not the question here.

Proof:
Let us simplify the recursion in order to arrive at this closed form.
The first observation is that the formula for $a_{n+1}$ contains a square in the denominator
but the one for $b_{n+1}$ does not. Together with Christian's observation that $(a_n,b_n)$ tends to $(\sqrt3,2)$ fast, this suggests to consider the sequence $b_{n}^2-a_{n}-1$ tending to 0.
It leads to the first formula:
$$b_{n+1}^2-a_{n+1}-1=\frac{(b_n^2-a_n-1)^2}{16b_n^2}.$$
The above formula suggests to introduce a new sequence $\{c_n\}_{n\geq1}$ by
$$\tag{1}c_n:=\sqrt{b_n^2-a_n-1}$$
so that $a_n=b_n^2-1-c_n^2$.
It follows that $b_n,c_n$ satisfy a simpler recurrence formula
$$\tag{2}c_{n+1}=\frac{c_n^2}{4b_n} \ \ \ b_{n+1}=\frac{b_n}2+\frac{6-c_n^2}{4b_n}.$$
Observe that the denominator in both formulas is the same; this is what makes it simpler.
The initial terms are now $c_1=\sqrt{5}$ and still $b_1=4$. All $c_n$, $n\geq2$, are rational,
however. We will use that $c_2=5/16$ and $b_2=33/16$.

A well known trick in such equations is to separate numerators and denominators.
So we put
$$\tag{3}c_n:=\frac{p_n}{q_n}\mbox{ and }b_n=\frac{r_n}{q_n}.$$
This might not be the reduced form of the fractions, but this is not needed. What we need is that
the sequences $\{c_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ satisfy the recursion (2) for $n\geq2$
if the sequences $\{p_n\},\{q_n\},\{r_n\}$ satisfy the recursion
$$\tag{4}p_{n+1}=p_n^2,\ \ \ q_{n+1}=4r_nq_n,\ \ \ r_{n+1}=2r_n^2+6q_n^2-p_n^2$$
for $n\geq2$ with initial terms $p_2=5,q_2=16,r_2=33$.
It follows immediately that $p_n=5^{2^{n-2}}$ for $n\geq2$,
but formulas for $r_n,q_n$ are not as easy to find.

Another well known trick helpful at this point
is to introduce a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\Z[\sqrt3]$:
$$x_n=r_n+q_n\sqrt3.$$
Then we obtain the following simple recursion for $p_n,x_n$
$$p_{n+1}=p_n^2,\ \ \ x_{n+1}=2x_n^2-p_n^2,$$
where $p_2=5$, $x_2=33+16\sqrt3$.

It is not helpful at this moment to use the closed form for $p_n$. It is better to  introduce
$y_n:=x_n/p_n$ which satisfies the recursion
$$\tag{5}y_{n+1}=2y_n^2-1,\ \ y_2=\frac{33+16\sqrt3}5$$
The right hand side of the recursion
recalls the formula for $\cos(2x)$ or, better suited in view of
$y_2>1$, for $\cosh(2x)$. This leads us to introduce a last sequence $z_n>1$ determined
by
$$\tag{6}y_n=:\frac12\left(z_n+\frac1{z_n}\right)$$
or $z_n:=y_n+\sqrt{y_n^2-1}$. The recursion (5) then reduces to
$$\tag{7}z_{n+1}=z_n^2, z_2=y_2+\sqrt{y_2^2-1}.$$
Finally we have explicitly $z_n=z_2^{2^{n-2}}$.

A small calculation using the well known formula for $\sqrt{c+d\sqrt{m}}$ yields
$\sqrt{y_2^2-1}=(22\sqrt2+12\sqrt6)/5$ so that
$$z_2=\tfrac15(33+16\sqrt3+22\sqrt2+12\sqrt6)=\tfrac15(11+4\sqrt6)(3+2\sqrt2)=
  \tfrac15(2\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^2(\sqrt2+1)^2.$$
We also use that $1/z_2=\frac15(-2\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^2(-\sqrt2+1)^2$.
We obtain using (6), $x_n=y_np_n$ and $p_n=5^{2^{n-2}}$
$$x_n=\tfrac1{2}\left((2\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^{2^{n-1}}(\sqrt2+1)^{2^{n-1}}+
    (-2\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^{2^{n-1}}(-\sqrt2+1)^{2^{n-1}} \right).$$
Observe that this is an expression in $\Z[\sqrt3]$: A priori, it is in
$\Z[\sqrt3][\sqrt2]$, but it is invariant under the ($\Z[\sqrt3]$)-endomorphism
generated by $\sqrt2\mapsto-\sqrt2$.

It remains to split $x_n=r_n+q_n\sqrt3$. This is done using the endomorphism $\phi$
of $\Z[\sqrt3]$ mapping $\sqrt3$ to $-\sqrt3$: We have $r_n=\tfrac12(x_n+\phi(x_n))$,
$q_n=\frac1{2\sqrt3}(x_n-\phi(x_n))$. We find the formulas of the answer for $n\geq2$.
Observe that the formulas are also valid for $n=1$, because they give $r_1=4$ and
$q_1=1$. The same holds for $c_1=\sqrt5=5^{2^{1-2}}$. This completes the proof.